# How to get cross-origin iframe content by Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to fetch images from cross-origin iframe (both main frame and iframe don't belong to me) and use my Chrome extension to analyze them. Apparently, I can't get the authority to access those servers.

I read a lot solutions about cross-origin scripting, but those methods require on your own server.

Any ideas for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be a Chrome extension? Have you considered a Chrome app instead?

Comment: The reason I have to use Chrome Extension is that I haven't use chrome app before. I don't know what capability of chrome app is.

Comment: Perhaps I provided a few information for you, let me clarify what exactly I want : "When you enable this extension and visit in any websites, it will get all target images in "all frames" and analyze them all the time(I use NPAPI to analyze images for this part and it works fine.)". So, is there any solutions by using chrome extension or chrome app?

Comment: I have the same problem. My chrome extension wants to manipulate elements of iframe in some random website. Whenever i try to use iframe.contentDocument , cross-origin issue occurs saying my content_script cannot access iframe. Please guide if you have something useful in this regard.